# Mobile Content Reference App

Tags: android, ios

I am looking to make static reference content available offline on iOS and and android. I have web dev experience but have not delved into smart phone dev. Is there a component or plugin or framework that will allow me to simply provide textual and graphical content and deliver the iOS/android app for that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the `Hybrid` approach. As you have experience with WebDev so `Phonegap` will come handy for you. Its just requires `HTML`, `Javascript, JQuery`. So its easy for you to develop on both `Android and iOS` and you can also run it on All smartphone like `BlackBerry, Windows phone`. Here the documentation for that. [Easily create apps using the web technologies you know and love: HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://phonegap.com/). Just walk through this [**Platform Guides**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html)